How can I estimate the population size from subpopulation statistics?
Say there is a some population of N samples that are sampled from an unknown Normal distribution, where N is unknown. The samples of the population are divided into k independent subpopulations, each with N/k samples. The mean and standard deviation of each of the subpopulations is known. How can I determine a good estimate of N?
Some intuition I have is that if the standard deviation of the means for k subpopulations is small compared to the standard deviation of the entire population (i.e. the means are close together), then N is likely larger. Additionally, if the standard deviation of k subpopulations are close together, then N is likely larger. I am having trouble finding an equation or algorithm that captures this intuition for estimating N.
Any insight helps, thank you.

‘population of N samples that are sampled from an unknown Normal distribution, where N is unknown.’ Would you take a moment to clarify this?

the population has a size N that we are trying to estimate. We don't know the population size, but we would like to.

You have not $N$ samples, but $N$ peoples, grouped in $k$ samples. For each people, there is a number (age for example), and for each group of $N/k$ peoples, you know mean and standard deviation of this variable age. Groups have been randomly created, so we can apply standard tools from statitstics. The variable is age or something similar, it is a variable that cannot be negative. Can you confirm that my understanding is correct ?

Using some dubious analysis and experiments:  if  you have $k$ sample means $\bar x_i$ and sample (Bessel corrected) variances $s_i^2$, then one possibility might be $\dfrac{\sum s_i^2}{ \textrm{var}(\bar x_i)}$.  Another might be $k +  \dfrac{2\left(\sum s_i^2\right)^2}{ k ,\textrm{var}(s_i^2)}$ .  Empirically, both often seem to give reasonable estimates of $N$ when $k$ is large but less so when $k$ is small. My guess is that there could be a better estimator than either of these.

Very interesting insight @Henry, I learned something here. +1

@Lourrran, yeah that sounds right, but the variable can be negative.

Your intuition is surely correct. But very difficult to 'retro-compute' the total size of the population. What is the standard number of samples $k$ in your process... maybe we can have some results for very small values of $k$, or very big ?

We have some theory : when we extract a sample of size $n$ from a large population, with standard deviation $d$ and average $m$, the average $m'$ of our sample will be close to $m$, and we have some formulas to estimate $\frac{m'-m}{d}$  ; these formulas are based on $\sqrt{n}$
Here, we do many samples.
I did some tests, and it works fine.
I have $k$ samples, each sample contains $n$ elements, and for each sample $S_i$, I have the average of all values $m_i$ and the standard deviation $d_i$.
I compute :
$D=$ average of all $d_i$
$M2=$ standard deviation of all $m_i$
$n$ can be estimated with : $n= (\frac{D}{M2})^2$
and then : $N= kn$
I did the tests with $k$ between $20$ and $100$, and $n$ between $100$ and $10000$.
